# HTML Entities to add a break-line into a link

Tags: javascript, php, html, xhtml

in Blogger code

```
<a class='whatsapp' expr:href='&quot;https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=&quot; + &quot;*&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;*&quot; + &quot; - &quot; + data:post.url.canonical + &quot; - &quot; + &quot;random text&quot;' rel='nofollow' title='Share to WhatsApp'></a>
```

I want to add a break line after data:post.title (the link) to be like the next image.. how? , is there a HTML Entities to add a break-line?

[with break-line , and without it image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87ns.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this %0a

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=data:title %0a %0a data:url random text

Answer (score 0):

In order to break-line we use `<br>` so add `<br>` after data:post.title

```
<a class='whatsapp' expr:href='&quot;https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=&quot; + &quot;*&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;<br>- &quot; + data:post.url.canonical + &quot; - &quot; + &quot;random text&quot;' rel='nofollow' title='Share to WhatsApp'></a>
```